# DateDiff Across Two Records that share same TypeID given list of TypeIDs w/o Looping

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

| ID | TypeID | StartDate | EndDate | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | cat | 2022/01/01 | 2022/02/01 | Jas |
| 02 | cat | 2022/03/01 | 2022/04/01 | Katy |
| 03 | dog | arb | arb | Gem |
| 04 | dog | arb | arb | Jas |
| 05 | dog | arb | arb | Katy |
| 06 | elephant | arb | arb | Carrot |
| 07 | elephant | arb | arb | Gemini |

Note: arb just means arbitrary dates since the logic is simple to DateDiff

Given the above table,

I would like to be able get the table with the following given the typeIDs(cat, dog) and Names(Jas, Katy):

| TypeId | DateDiff | Start Name to End Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cat | 3 | Jas to Katy |
| dog | arb | Jas to Katy |

Given typeIDs(cat, dog) and Names(Katy, Jas):

| TypeId | DateDiff | Start Name to End Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cat | -1 | Katy to Jas |
| dog | arb | Katy to Jas |

DateDiff would get the start date of the first name and subtract that from the end date of the second name.
I have figured out a way to do this by looping through the typeIds and selecting from the table and using DateDiff function and etc., but I understand that this is bad practice and very slow. I am trying to work on a set-based solution, but I am sort of stuck. I have tried to do Group By TypeID, but it only works with aggregate functions.

FYI: this is just an example table that resembles a part of a much larger table I am working on.

Comment: What does subtracting `arb` from `arb` mean here, it's not a number? And what happened to `elephant` in the results? And why does `dog` get `Jas to Katy` and not `Gem to Katy`?

Comment: Sounds like you want something like this https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3005c9326c9e7ecf6b80195bba2ffe5a but unclear as mentioned

Comment: Sorry to specify. arb just means arbitrary number since the logic is simple DateDiff(day,StartDate,EndDate). Elephant is not in the result since only cat and dog was given in the list of TypeIDs. Jas to Katy is due to the Names (Jas,Katy) being given to the query

Comment: [`DateDiff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) works with dates. What date is `'2022/01'`? Do you perform the division and then advance `2022` Base Cycle Croutons beyond 17 November 1858? What `datepart`, returned from `DateDiff`, would be `'03'`? Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an `IN` clause to filter those columns, then `GROUP BY TypeId`.

You also need conditional aggregation to get the dates

```sql
DECLARE @types TABLE (typeId varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT @types VALUES ;

DECLARE @from varchar(20) = 'Jas';
DECLARE @to varchar(20) = 'Katy';

SELECT
  t.TypeId,
  DateDiff = DATEDIFF(month, MIN(CASE WHEN t.Name = @from THEN t.StartDate END), MAX(CASE WHEN t.Name = @to THEN t.EndDate END)),
  [Name to Name] = @from + ' to ' + @to
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.TypeId IN ('cat', 'dog')
  AND t.Name IN (@from, @to)
GROUP BY
  t.TypeID;
```

Ideally you would parameterize this properly using a Table Valued Parameter or a temp table.

```sql
DECLARE @types TABLE (typeId varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT @types VALUES ('cat'),('dog');

DECLARE @from varchar(20) = 'Jas';
DECLARE @to varchar(20) = 'Katy';

SELECT
  t.TypeId,
  DateDiff = DATEDIFF(month, MIN(CASE WHEN t.Name = @from THEN t.StartDate END), MAX(CASE WHEN t.Name = @to THEN t.EndDate END)),
  [Name to Name] = @from + ' to ' + @to
FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.TypeId IN (SELECT tp.TypeId FROM @types tp)
  AND t.Name IN (@from, @to)
GROUP BY
  t.TypeID;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90ded453ea3b76b4590a6a559161c2be)

Note that this assumes that `StartDate` and `EndDate` are actual `datetime` values, not weird strings.

Comment: Thank you this is helpful. However does this query assume that MIN(t.StartDate) belongs to the first name and MAX(t.EndDate) belongs to the second name? It should not according to my data

Comment: No it doesn't: `MIN` will be the lowest in the group and `MAX` will be the maximum, when sorted A-Z

Comment: When I do Katy to Jas instead of Jas to Katy, it gives me the same number for DateDiff when it should be negative instead. The query should work for cases when the names aren't in A-Z order.

Comment: That seems to be a different question. You are saying you have a *from* name and a *to* name, and you want to know the difference betweent them?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, sorry if that wasn't specific enough

Comment: OK have modified